# Failover of the temporary queues with ActiveMQ not working

Tags: jms, activemq-classic

I have 4 ActiveMQ brokers

- 2 Front-end which are "linked" with each other
- 2 Back-end which are "linked" with each other

The front-end brokers are linked with the backend brokers through a bridge. Imagine a square and that at the corners are the brokers. This means that a front-end broker is bridged with only one backend broker.
For some specific parts of the application we do request-reply.
Our scenario is that we have a client which connects to the front-end brokers `failover:(tcp://localhost:61618,tcp://localhost:61619)` and an application which connects to the back-end brokers with `failover:(tcp://localhost:61616,tcp://localhost:61617)`.

During a failover test when one back-end broker is terminated ( nicely, meaning shutdown ) the temporary queue created on the broker which is terminated is not being recreated on the remaining back-end broker.

In our back-end broker we have set the below attributes to true `advisorySupport="true" cacheTempDestinations="true"`

The network connectors looks like below for the backend:

```
<networkConnectors>
            <networkConnector name="broker1QueuesBridge"
                uri="static:(nio://localhost:61617)"
                dynamicOnly="true" decreaseNetworkConsumerPriority="true"
                networkTTL="4">
                <excludedDestinations>
                    <topic physicalName=">" />
                    <queue physicalName="*.out" />
                    <queue physicalName="*.*.out" />
                </excludedDestinations>
            </networkConnector>
            <networkConnector name="broker1TopicsBridge"
                uri="static:(nio://localhost:61617)"
                dynamicOnly="true" decreaseNetworkConsumerPriority="true"
                suppressDuplicateQueueSubscriptions="true" networkTTL="4">
                <excludedDestinations>
                    <queue physicalName=">" />
                </excludedDestinations>
            </networkConnector>
            <networkConnector name="fbroker1Bridge"
                uri="static:(nio://localhost:61618?keepAlive=true)"
                networkTTL="4" dynamicOnly="true">
                <excludedDestinations>
                    <queue physicalName="queue.out" />                           
                </excludedDestinations>
            </networkConnector>
        </networkConnectors>
```

And for front-end they are configured like:

```
    <networkConnectors>
        <networkConnector name="fbroker2QueuesBridge"
            uri="static:(nio://localhost:61619)"
            dynamicOnly="true" decreaseNetworkConsumerPriority="true"
            networkTTL="4" bridgeTempDestinations="true">
            <excludedDestinations>
                <topic physicalName=">" />
                <queue physicalName="*.out" />
                <queue physicalName="*.*.out" />
            </excludedDestinations>
        </networkConnector>
        <networkConnector name="fbroker2TopicsBridge"
            uri="static:(nio://localhost:61619)"
            dynamicOnly="true" decreaseNetworkConsumerPriority="true"
            suppressDuplicateQueueSubscriptions="true" networkTTL="4" bridgeTempDestinations="true"> 
            <excludedDestinations>
                <queue physicalName=">" />
            </excludedDestinations>
        </networkConnector>
        <networkConnector name="broker1Bridge"
            uri="static:(nio://localhost:61616?keepAlive=true)"
            dynamicOnly="true" networkTTL="4" bridgeTempDestinations="true" >
            <excludedDestinations>
                <queue physicalName="queue.out" />
            </excludedDestinations>
        </networkConnector>
    </networkConnectors>
```

Any ideas why this is happening ? Do i miss some configuration or is just something not configured properly ?

```
Thanks in advance.
```